# foreach loop for $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I have form containing many input fields. But I need to take one field from form using foreach loop.

```
foreach ($_POST['image'] as $image):
//mysql query to insert 
endforeach;
```

How can I take posted value for 'image' using for each loop? I need to get each image name using this foreach loop.

Thanks!

Comment: So where is the problem? Your given code will do foreach loop for `$_POST['image']`

Comment: Are the inputs of type `file`? If so you will need the correct enctype (`enctype="multipart/form-data"`) on the form and to access the `$_FILES` super global and not `$_POST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used input type="file" you have to check following things

1. your form must have attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" included in form tag.
2. You cannot get file name from $_POST array, rather you should use $_FILES['fieldname']['name'];

Answer (score 0):

Your need to use $_FILES. In your form, if an image input is....

... input type="file" name="image" id="image" />

... to get image name you need to use $_FILES['image']['name']